# how to use jquery click inside an iframe on same domain

Tags: jquery, iframe, click

My parent page uses Jquery.

I'm loading an iframe onto this parent page that calls another page. The iframe page is on the same domain.

The iframe page itself, does not have jQuery associated to it.

But I want to use jQuery's click method on a button that is inside this iframe page.

How can I do this from the parent page .js file? ...without attaching the jQuery source file to the iframe page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the method `.contents()` and then `.find()` to get to your element, like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#yourbutton').click(function(){
    //Do whatever you need
});
```

Of course you'd have to change your selectors to be more specific

Comment: since this is in an iframe, what if i want to add make sure that on click, its communicating with the parent window?  (i.e. window.parent)? how would you adjust your example?  And I apologize darkajax if that was not in my original question.

Comment: Thank you darkajax for giving me the answer to my initial question!

Comment: @blachawk don't worry, and It'll be communicating with it by anything like, let's say: `$('element outside iframe').html($('iframe').contents().find('element inside iframe').text())` you'd see it'll change because it's affected...